# Replace a specific set of special characters with text boxes and retrieve value from each of the text boxes

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to implement a scenario, where a student can answer fill in the blanks type question. There can be multiple number of blanks in a single question. The question is comping from API.

What I'm trying to achieve is, replacing each of the special characters with ***"text box"***, students can type their answers in that text boxes. When I'll save the answer, the entire string will be saved.

Eg:

Question: John ___ going ___ school. He is ___ good boy.

This should be rendered as:

John  going  school. He is  good boy.

When sending it to API, I'll send this as a string, like *John is going to school. He is a good boy.*

How I'll achieve this in Angular with TypeScript..

Any help or idea to do this in other way, is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sk8rl8)

You need to split the question by `___` and then append an input after every index of the split result.

```
parts = [];
inputControls = [];

parts = this.question.split('___');
```

Then in your template

```
<div>
  <span *ngFor="let p of parts; let i = index;">{{p}}
    <span *ngIf="i < parts.length -1">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputControls[i]" /></span>
    </span>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" style="margin-top: 40px; background-color: green; color: white" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Inside submit method, compose your answer like

```
submit(){
    let answer = '';

    for(let i = 0; i < this.parts.length; i++){
        answer += this.parts[i];
        if(i < this.inputControls.length)
          answer += this.inputControls[i];
    }

    console.log(answer);
  }
```

Comment: Almost achieved what I wanted, but when I'm rendering the HTML with **[(ngModel)]="inputControls[i]"** only one input text field is rendering, removing this part is rendering the HTML correctly. When the it is rendering incompletely, if I press the submit button, rest of the part is rendered. Don't know why this behaviour.

Comment: It worked. I was using this with formGroup, that's why I was getting the error. Worked just fine.